# The array class in C# - Implementation questions

Tags: c#, .net, array

I am studying the `Array` class in C#. The following is the implementation of `System.Array` class:

```
[SerializableAttribute] 
[ComVisibleAttribute(true)] 
public abstract class Array : ICloneable, IList, ICollection, IEnumerable, IStructuralComparable, IStructuralEquatable
```

I have two questions regarding this:

1. I have read that `System.Array` class is derived from `System.Object`. But why is this not seen in the above definition?
2. ICloneable is implemented in order to allow the Array to be Deep-Copied in case of XML serialization. ICloneable provides only one method - Clone(). What is the advantage of implementing ICloneable explicitly? Why could not Clone() method be directly implemented? Is this a type of providing a Marking Interface pattern where a particular Interface is implemented only to convey a certain characteristic of the class?

Comment: It is not seen because _every_ object derives from `Object`. It is implicit.

Comment: @Oded, If it is not seen, then it should be specified somewhere, right? It is somewhat confusing... Surely the fact that every object derives from `Object` would not be the only reason... Don't you think?

Comment: It **is** documented that every type is derived from `Object`.

Comment: @Oded, What I meant was, how does the compiler know? Documentation is for humans...

Comment: It is probably built into the compiler...

Comment: If you disassemble into IL code, you will see that `System.Array` extends from `System.Object`. As Oded points out, this information is  implicit in higher level languages such as C# & VB. *"If it is not seen, then it should be specified somewhere, right?"* - Yes, it is specified in the IL.

Comment: @TheSilverBullet  It's a given that everything extends from `System.Object`.  The compiler allows you to omit specifying it because you can't prevent it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. `System.Array` is effectively derived from `System.Object`. You don't see it here, because everything in .NET Framework derives by default from `System.Object`, including types like `int` (`System.Int32`).

   In other words:

   - `class MyClass : MyOtherClass { }` indicates that `MyClass` is derived from `MyOtherClass`.
   - `class MyClass { }` indicates that `MyClass` is derived from `System.Object`.
2. The advantage of using an interface is that methods (or classes with generics) may rely on interfaces when they need a specific method or property. Imagine the following source code:

   ```
   public interface INamed
   {
       string Name { get; }
   }

   public void SayHello(INamed namedEntity)
   {
       Console.WriteLine("Hello, " + namedEntity.Name + "!");
   }
   ```

   By using an interface, the method shows that it doesn't care about the exact type of `namedEntity`. All what it cares about is that the object should contain a property of type `string` called `Name` which has a getter.

   The actual type may be a `Person`. Or a `Cat : Animal`. Or an `AircraftModel`. `SayHello` accepts them all, at the condition for them to implement `INamed`.

   Why would `Person` implement an interface, instead of simply containing the `Name` property?

   Because, aside using Reflection or dynamic programming, the caller doesn't have a clue that `Person` effectively implements `Name` property. For example this code will not compile:

   ```
   public class Person
   {
       public string Name { get; set; }
   }

   public void SayHello(object namedEntity)
   {
       Console.WriteLine("Hello, " + namedEntity.Name + "!"); // Compile-time error here
   }

   public void Main()
   {
       this.SayHello(new Person { Name = "Robert" });
   }
   ```

Comment: Just rephrasing so that I am sure I understood. For point 1, the very fact that `Array` is a class means that it is derived from `System.Object`.  For point 2, as assumed, the idea behind implementng `ICloneable` is to "tell" the user that the class implements `Clone()` function. Am I correct?

Comment: For the point 2, that's correct. For the point 1, a class may be derived from another class, which in turn derives for a third class, etc., but finally, the Nth class will derive from `System.Object`.

Comment: @TheSilverBullet "_to "tell" the user that the class implements Clone()_" Not quite.  It's to allow you to write methods that use any cloneable object without caring what kind of object it is.

Comment: @TheSilverBullet its not so much telling the user the class implements Clone(), rather its giving the user the option to create  the method to take any class that implements the IClonable interface. Since it is reference by the interface, the method does not care what class is being passed since it only cares about the methods that the IClonable interface provides.

Comment: @RossPatterson, I get the perspective now. This looks like a facilitator for familiar design pattern. (Strategy?)